# Building TG bot with python giving me "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to build a Telegram bot to share my open jobs (I'm a technical recruiter).

Everything looks good with the code, but I keep getting this error:

`TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

It's also saying bug is in this line

```
updater = telegram.ext.updater("API_KEY", use_context = True)
```

I know it has to do something with the import and using it.

But not sure how to fix this.

I've imported the correct library with:

`pip3 install python-telegram-bot`

Any help is welcome!

```
import telegram.ext

Token = "API_KEY"

updater = telegram.ext.updater("API_KEY", use_context = True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

def start(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text("Hello! Thanks for messaging me!")

def help(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text(
        """
        /aboutme -> More info about me.
        /jobs -> See all my open jobs!
        /myinfo -> My email information.
        /latamsalaries -> Current LATAM salaries for devs.
        """
    )

def aboutme(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text("My name is Robert Grootjen, and I'm a technical headhunter! My mission is to connect the best talent in Latin America with topnotch companies in the United States and Canada.")

def jobs(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text("")

def myinfo(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text("Linkedin: https://www.linkedin.com/in/robert-grootjen-08a10b15a/")

def latamsalaries(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text("Jr - $1500 - $3000 USD")


dispatcher.add_handler(telegram.ext.CommandHandler('start', start))
dispatcher.add_handler(telegram.ext.CommandHandler('aboutme', aboutme))
dispatcher.add_handler(telegram.ext.CommandHandler('jobs', jobs))
dispatcher.add_handler(telegram.ext.CommandHandler('myinfo', myinfo))
dispatcher.add_handler(telegram.ext.CommandHandler('latamsalaries', latamsalaries))

updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

Answer (score 0):

Code looks fine.

I Hope you are running this code in vscode without setting python workenvironment. try by running `python -m (path_to_py)`

if thats not the case, then look:[Type Error: module obj...](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable-python-error-solved/)

Comment: I'm running the code in vscode.

Tried your command and got:

"zsh: number expected"

Comment: @RobertGrootjen, Hide your API key. Need more info on the error. check this link:https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/issues/1879